# Trouble Viewing File Upload Data in Excel Export with Custom Sitecore Form Element

Tags: jss, sitecore-forms

I have created a custom Form Element in Sitecore form named "File Upload Email".
There are two validators

1. File Size validator

[image]

2. Content Type Validator.

[image]

According to my current code,validators are working fine but am unable to see the saved data related to file upload in exported excel sheet.
[image]
What do I need to so I can be able to see the saved data related to File Upload Email?
Putting the code below:-

```
const JssNextForm = ({ fields, router }: any) => {
  const { sitecoreContext } = useSitecoreContext();
  const [customFieldFactory, setCustomFieldFactory] = useState<FieldFactory | null>(null);
useEffect(() => {
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const customFieldFactory = createDefaultFieldFactory();
  customFieldFactory.setComponent(
    '{687A7B09-47E3-4FAA-AB2D-A4BF83DB0F1B}',
    ({ field }: ValueFieldProps<InputViewModel>) => {
      field.valueField.value = field.model.value as string;
      const conditionSettings = field.model.conditionSettings as ConditionSettings;
      const fieldKey = conditionSettings?.fieldKey;
      const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const file = event.target.files && event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
          if (file.size > (field.model.maxFileSize as number)) {
            alert(
              `File size exceeds the maximum allowed size of ${
                field.model.maxFileSize as number
              } bytes.`
            );
            return;
          }
          if (!(field.model.allowedContentTypes as string[]).includes(file.type)) {
            alert('Invalid file type.');
            return;
          }
          field.valueField.value = file.name; // Assigning file name as value
        }
      };
      return (
        <div className="form-row">
          <label
            className={'file-type-label ' + field.model.labelCssClass}
            htmlFor={field.valueField.id}
          >
            {field.model.title}
          </label>
          <div className="form-input--file-type">
            <input
              id={field.valueField.id}
              name={field.valueField.name}
              className={field.model.cssClass}
              type="file"
              data-sc-tracking={field.model.isTrackingEnabled}
              data-sc-field-name={field.model.name}
              data-sc-field-key={fieldKey}
              onChange={handleFileChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor={field.valueField.id}>
              {field.model.buttonDisplayText as string}
            </label>
            <span className="file-name">{field.valueField.value}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  );
  setCustomFieldFactory(customFieldFactory);
  }
 }, []);

if (!customFieldFactory) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        form={fields}
        sitecoreApiHost={''}
        sitecoreApiKey={config.sitecoreApiKey}
        fieldFactory={customFieldFactory}
        onRedirect={(url) => router.push(url)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```